# viewHolder null and scrollToPosition incorrect

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, bind, android-viewholder

I'm trying to implement selection of the first recycler view item + scrolling to position in a very simillar way of Sunshine ForecastFragment

https://github.com/udacity/Advanced_Android_Development/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/ForecastFragment.java

But I keep facing 2 problems :

scrolling is not always correct and 
viewHolder is sometime null (and I need access to it in order to display the first row)

I first thaught this is due to the fact that when scrolling is incorrect the view is not on screen and the holder is not binded. So I tried several things.

First I tried that

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    Log.e("FF", Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2] + "swapCursor ");
    mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {

            if (mRecyclerView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                // Since we know we're going to get items, we keep the listener around until
                // we see Children.
                mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                int position = mAdapter.getSelectedItemPosition(getContext());
                if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    position = mPosition == null ? getFirstContactPosition(mAdapter) : mPosition;
                }
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

                //this method findViewHolderForAdapterPosition will always return null if we
                // call it after a swapCursor
                //(because it always return null after a notifyDataSetChanged) that's why we
                // call findViewHolderForAdapterPosition in the onPreDraw method
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

                Log.e("FF", Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2] + "vh " + vh);
                if (null != vh) {
                    if (getResources().getInteger(R.integer.orientation) == MainActivity.W700dp_LAND)
                        mAdapter.selectView(vh);
                }
                mPosition = position;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Then I tried replacing

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

with every posible solutions I found

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position);
mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(position);
mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 20);
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

then I tried executing the scroll in postDelayed thread as follow

```
final int finalPosition = position;
mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(finalPosition);
    }
}, 1000);
```

all of that with no success.

Now I have no clue in what directions to look for. And I'm still not completely sure of the fact that the viewHolder is null is due to the incorrect scroll.
Here are the correct behavior I have when I select an onScreen item

```
on first orientation change
    - scrolling is correct
    - view holder is not null
on second and following orientation change
    - same as before, it work well
```

And here is the behaviour I have when I select an offScreen item

```
on first orientation change
    - scrolling is correct
    - view holder IS null
on second and following orientation change
    - scrolling is incorrect (seems to scroll to the last onScreen item)
    - view holder is NOT null
on third orientation change
    - like first
on fourth orientation change
    - like second
etc
```

Note by onScreen I mean the items that are first shown to the user without need to scroll.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.